# TikZ single intersection between curve and horizontal line not found

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, intersections

### What happened

The error

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-1' is known.
```

is produced when compiling the following with `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[name path=line,smooth] (0,4.5)--(1.5,4.5);
        \draw[name path=curve,smooth] (1.5,6) to[out=270,in=90] (0,3);
        \draw[name intersections={of=line and curve}] (intersection-1) circle[radius=0.1]; % Error here
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When commenting out the intersection-searching line in the code above, the following diagram is produced:

[image]

Clearly, there exists exactly one intersection between the curve and the line.

---

### General purpose of code

Given an arbitrary `y` coordinate, e.g., `y=4.5`, I want to find the corresponding `x` coordinate on a given curve *after* the curve was drawn (I learn what the `y` coordinate is only after the curve is processed.) Therefore, I create the horizontal line `(0,4.5)--(1.5,4.5)`, intentionally extending it in the `x` direction to ensure that it intersects with the curve, and then proceed to finding the intersection between the two. After the intersection is found, I `\path` to it and then call `\pgfgetlastxy` to find the `x` coordinate as `pt` (not shown on the MWE.)

The intention is to include the code in an already-existing `LaTeX`-written book composed by my Master's research supervisor, which is moving towards completion. As such, changing the typesetting system to anything other than `pdfLaTeX` is, for practical reasons, impossible at this stage.

---

### Research so far

1. **Zarko** in their answer to [TikZ intersection not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434729/tikz-intersection-not-found) suggests discarding units (`pt`, `cm`, etc.) in the code, but my example doesn't use any units.
2. **Qrrbrbirlbel** in their answer to [TikZ doesn't find all intersections between plot and a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127400/tikz-doesnt-find-all-intersections-between-plot-and-a-line) advises to use the `smooth` option, but the example above uses it in the drawing of both the curve and the line, without success.
3. **Gonzalo Medina** in their answer to [TikZ not computing intersection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229297/tikz-not-computing-intersection) urges to remove spaces between coordinates and the `--` connectors, which my MWE is using, again without results.
4. **Zarko** notices in [Intersection between several lines and a curve using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599069/intersection-between-several-lines-and-a-curve-using-tikz) that the reason for the error is that some curves simply don't intersect, but the curve and line in the MWE above clearly do.
5. To demonstrate that the `intersections` `Tikz` library succeeds in finding intersections for similar cases, I run the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[name path=line,smooth] (0,5)--(1.5,5);
        \draw[name path=curve,smooth] (1.5,6) to[out=270,in=90] (0,3);
        \draw[name intersections={of=line and curve}] (intersection-1) circle[radius=0.1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which successfully generates

[image]

[Thanks to **hpekristiansen** for the recommendation to use `circle` instead of the uncentered and hard-to-see `$\circ$` and to **gernot** for the recommendation to shorten the curve to the segment `y in [3,6]`, which is where the issue occurs.]

---

### Software Specifications

Executing `pdflatex --version` in my Windows 10's CMD outputs

```
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.0.1 (MiKTeX 20.7)
© 1982 D. E. Knuth, © 1996-2020 Hàn Thế Thành
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010
compiled with curl version 7.61.1; using libcurl/7.61.1 WinSSL
compiled with expat version 2.2.6; using expat_2.2.6
compiled with jpeg version 9.3
compiled with liblzma version 50020042; using 50020042
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 2.8.2; using LibreSSL 2.8.2
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with poppler version 0.60.1
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.2
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
```

When placing `\listfiles` at the top of the document, the following information is output to the console:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
     pgf.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
graphicx.sty    2019/11/30 v1.2a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2019/11/30 v1.4a Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
  pgffor.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
l3backend-pdfmode.def    2020-08-07 L3 backend support: PDF mode
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
 ***********
```

---

How should the code in the 1st MWE be corrected to eliminate the error, without loading additional libraries into the document?

I am aware that there might exist other methods in `TikZ` to find the `x` coordinate on the curve based on the `y` coordinate (and will be thankful also to answers that mention such methods,) but I am primarily interested in learning why `TikZ` doesn't detect the intersection in the specific MWE above.

---

### UPDATE 11/12/2021

- Removing the `smooth` options doesn't remove the error. Thanks to **gernot** for suggesting this possible change.
- Compiling with `LuaLaTeX` doesn't solve the problem either, as the same error `` ! Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-1' is known. `` persists. Thanks to **user202729** for suggesting this possible change.
- Even slight changes in the coordinates or the direction degrees eliminate the problem, as **Ignasi** and **gernot** noticed, but I seek to find a solution that preserves the numbers in the question.
- **gernot** opened an issue on `pgf`'s GitHub page as the 1st practical step to address the issue. You may follow the unfolding of the issue at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1076. Great thanks to **gernot** for their contribution!

---

### UPDATE 11/13/2021

I would like to thank **ABC** for the noticeably simple solution to the problem (see below!)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove the `smooth` options, twice. Then it works, and the image looks fine.

Comment: @gernot, thank you very much for your reply! After removing the 2 ```smooth``` instances, I am still getting the same error ```! Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-1' is known.```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I get the error, too. Red herring.

Comment: BTW, you have the problem thoroughly investigated. At least concerning the style, your posting could be published at some high-class conference. ;-)

Comment: @gernot, thank you very much for your kind words! Would you like to edit the question to add that the removal of ```smooth``` didn't eliminate the error? I'll then accept your editing suggestion.

Comment: Don't you see the `edit` button left below your posting? Not sure whether this is bound to some reputation.

Comment: @gernot, thank you for your reply! Edit is available for me. I asked because you came up with the suggestion, so I thought that it will be natural that this edit will be also made by you.

Comment: It seems to be a low level problem. If you vary the `y` coordinate of the line and choose something different from `4.5`, it works.

Comment: I think there is a problem with inner computations, it works for 4.49 a 4.51 but not for 4.5.

Comment: Exactly! This is strange, but TikZ should overcome possibly 'extreme' computational cases.

Comment: You could reduce the problem to one segment, as it seems to be a numeric problem: `\draw[name path=line] (0,4.5)--(1.5,4.5);\draw[name path=curve]  (1.5,6) to[out=270,in=90] (0,3);` As a work-around, you could use `270.1` instead of `270`. These Bezier curves are approximations anyway.

Comment: Unrelated: Replace `node {$\circ$};` with `circle[radius=0.06];` to get a circle that is centred on the coordinate.

Comment: @lgnasi and @gernot, great thanks for your suggestions. I will edit the question as @gernot indicates to focus on the problematic segment. Although changing to ```270.1``` won't significantly contort the image, I still seek a solution that preserves both the coordinates and the bending directions. Since the issue is most likely technical, as you mentioned, I might eventually report it as a bug.

Comment: TikZ mostly use string operations to "emulate" floating point computation, and it does have a few known errors... so try compiling with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, thank you very much! This is a great edit suggestion. I will also increase the radius to make it more visible.

Comment: @user202729, thank you for the recommendation! This code is supposed to become a part of an existing LaTeX-based book that my Master's thesis supervisor writes. As such, shifting to LuaLaTeX may be quite inconvenient given the existing work. UPDATE: When compiling with Lua, the same error still persists: ```! Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-1' is known.```

Comment: @MiriamBriskman I filed an issue, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1076 (with a back reference)

Comment: @gernot, thank you very much for doing so! I set my GitHub to 'Watch' this thread. Hopefully, the request will receive proper attention from the creators.

Comment: If you change the ordering, it works: `\draw[name intersections={of=curve and line}] (intersection-1) circle[radius=0.1];`. The problem might thus be related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644.

Comment: @ABC, your solution perfectly works! Thank you very much for figuring out how to effectively solve the issue! Could you, please, write your solution as an answer to the main question? In addition, could you explain (perhaps also in your answer,) the connection between the issue and the question at tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644, as the latter (1) executes without errors, and (2) uses the ```sort by``` key, which the current question doesn't? Again, great thanks for your helpful input!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: this is not a complete answer in that it does not solve the underlying issue but just allows one to evade its consequences, i.e. it is something you could call workaround.

When `tikz` computes intersections between two paths, it sorts them by one of the two paths, and the default is to sort by the first path. However, under [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418644) it has been found that this does not always work as expected if the sorting path is a line. Indeed, if we either change the order of the paths:

```
name intersections={of=line and curve} -> name intersections={of=curve and line}
```

or tell `tikz` to sort by the second path:

```
name intersections={of=line and curve,sort by=curve}
```

the problem goes away. Note, however, that the `bend left=0` trick does not seem to work in this case (unless I am missing something). (I kept the `smooth` keys in the code even though they do not have an effect because the paths do not include `plot`s, just to reiterate that the problem has nothing to do with the `smooth` keys.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[name path=line,smooth] (0,4.5) -- (1.5,4.5);
        \draw[name path=curve,smooth] (1.5,6) to[out=270,in=90] (0,3);
        \draw[name intersections={of=curve and line}] (intersection-1) circle[radius=0.1]; % Error here
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[name path=line,smooth] (0,4.5) -- (1.5,4.5);
        \draw[name path=curve,smooth] (1.5,6) to[out=270,in=90] (0,3);
        \draw[name intersections={of=line and curve,sort by=curve}] (intersection-1) circle[radius=0.1]; % Error here
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much again for the perfectly-working workaround/solution! Hopefully, the contributors to ```TikZ``` will eliminate the issue in the next patch.

Comment: @MiriamBriskman You're welcome and I agree. In my opinion it is already amazing how well intersections work given that the computations are done by TeX, but I agree that without this issue it would be even better.